# ¿Cómo puedo obtener más detalles sobre las conexiones activas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Como es sabido, puedo obtener el número total de conexiones activas en MySQL mediante la siguiente consulta:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

Pero quiero saber **si es posible obtener más detalles sobre cada conexión**, teniendo en cuenta que se trata de una base de datos remota, la cual se encuentra alojada en un **hosting compartido** (Bluehost).

El tipo de información adicional que me gustaría conocer sería más o menos la siguiente: la IP desde la cual se ha establecido cada conexión, la última consulta ejecutada, la fecha/hora de conexión, el nombre de usuario con el cual se ha establecido la conexión.

¿Existe alguna manera de conocer esos detalles?

### EDIT

A pesar de ser una BD alojada en hosting compartido (Bluehost), parece que tengo todos los privilegios en la misma.

Al ejecutar:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

Obtengo:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mi-usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my\database`.* TO 'mi-usuario'@'localhost'
```

Answer (score 2):

Me suena que con esto igual te sirve.

```
show processlist
```

Comment: Es correcto. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: Gracias. `show processlist` me muestra `user, host, db, command...` etc, pero una sola fila, la cual imagino es de mi conexión actual. Pero la idea es mostrar los detalles de cada conexión activa. O sea, que me de más o menos esos datos, pero para **todas** las conexiones, las cuales oscilan entre 10 y 15 más o menos.

Comment: En teoria te muestra una conexion por linea. O eso creo.

Comment: Actualmente yo ejecuto `SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';` y me muestra un total de `9` conexiones activas, pero al ejecutar `show processlist` me muestra solamente una fila, la cual corresponderá (imagino) **a mi conexión**, pero yo quiero ver los detalles de las otras 8 conexiones.  O sea, debería mostrar 9 filas en vez de 1.

Comment: La doc dice: _If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see **all threads**. **Otherwise, you can see only your own threads** (**that is, threads associated with the MySQL account that you are using**). If you do not use the FULL keyword, only the first 100 characters of each statement are shown in the Info field._ Al parecer no tengo el privilegio PROCESS, no sé si al ser una bd remota en hosting compartido ese privilegio está bloqueado. Me extrañaría, porque mi bd es propia, aunque esté alojada en hosting compartido (Bluehost). Aunque la parte entre paréntesis me deja confundido.

Comment: Igual al ser remota, no tienes un usuario administrador, tendra un usuario normal con bastantes privilegios, pero igual no eres root.

Comment: Al parecer tengo todos los privilegios (ver EDIT en la pregunta).

Comment: Es una base de datos de un hosing, o una vps?

Comment: Es una base de datos en hosting compartido (Bluehost).

Comment: Entonces seguramente no tegas todos los privilegios, tendras todos, menos el de admin, o algo asi

Comment: Como he puesto en la pregunta actualizada, me dice que tengo: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` ¿eso no significa que tengo privilegios de administrador? De todos modos la doc dice que en caso de no tener el privilegio `PROCESS` no podría ver los procesos de **otros** usuarios, no dice que tendría limitaciones en cuanto al usuario actual, que es lo que me interesa, ya que la BD tiene ese solo usuario.

Comment: En teoria si, pero al ser un hosting, igual te capa alguno

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

- **Threads_cached**. Es el número de procesos cacheados actualmente.
- **Threads_connected**. Número de conexiones activas actualmente.
- **Threads_create**. Las conexiones que se han creado hasta el momento.
- **Threads_running**. Las que se están ejecutando actualmente.

```
show status like 'Threads%';
```